# Como posso printar uma imagem apenas na ultima linha de uma tabela no jasper reports

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

Tenho uma tabela que tem saida em PDF no jasper reports e preciso de uma expressão booleana para printar uma imagem apenas na ultima linha da tabela.
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por que você não coloca essa imagem no sumário do relatório?

Comment: esse relatorio não possui sumario, e quando digo imagem, nao é a mesma, pode ser uma seta para cima e uma seta para baixo (indicador de lucro por grupo)

Comment: Coloque um sumário e escolha a imagem através de uma logica qualquer.

Comment: Consegui achar a solução para esse problema com o uso da variável interna do jasper:

$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @ReginaldoRigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução para esse problema com o uso da variável interna do jasper:

`$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()`

Ela funciona como um contador de linhas da faixa de detalhes da sua tabela, então é só eu utilizar ela na  da imagem e adicionar ela nas linhas que você precisar.